# svg-insertAdjacentHTML is not working on firefox version 35 and below?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

I'm trying to draw a line by using svg. So I was used the `insertAdjacentHTML`. But this is working on chrome but not working in firefox.

My html code as follow

```
<div style="height:330px; width:1100px; background:#313131; margin:0 auto; ">
    <svg id='svg_main' height="330" width="1100"></svg>
</div>
```

My javascript is as follow

```
var svgid = document.getElementById('svg_main');
var str_lne = 60;
var data = '<path id="lineAB" d="M 50 '+str_lne+' L 1050 '+(str_lne)+'" transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"  stroke="#707073" fill="none"  storke-width="1px" opacity="1" ></path>';
svgid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',data);
```

It doesn't run by the localhost on the firefox(below 35).

For example,

I open the firefox and enter the url (localhost/svgtest.html) now the svg line is not showing. But, I save the page by ctrl+s and open by firefox it shows the line.

[image: run on the firefox by using localhost]  [image: simply open the file on firefox]Please help me out from this problem and clarify the reson of the problem.

Comment: The latest versio of Firefox is now 47. Firefox 35 is unsafe to use as it has known security holes. Upgrade before you regret not doing so.

Comment: In future, please do not edit your questions such that they invalidate existing answers. Instead, **ask a new question**.

Comment: @Matt okay. I'll change myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace the following:

```
svgid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data);
```

with the following:

```
console.log('SVG\'s NS before insertion: ' + svgid.namespaceURI);
svgid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data);
console.log('SVG\'s NS after insertion: ' + svgid.namespaceURI);
pathEl = document.getElementById('lineAB');
console.log('PATH\'s NS (after insertion): ' + pathEl.namespaceURI);
```

Try it with Firefox 35 or below. This is to see what the namespace of the SVG element is before and after the call to `insertAdjacentHTML` and what the namespace of the PATH element is, after it has been inserted.

You could also try [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1j393u0/), which contains the modification suggested above.

What you encounter is related to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=886390). The fix for this bug landed on Firefox 36. Up to and excluding Firefox 36, messing with the inner HTML of an SVG element would not respect the element's deduced `svg` namespace and elements inserted would belong to the `xhtml` namespace. Regarded, then, as an HTML element, PATH element `#lineAB` would make no sense and would, thus, disappear from the page. But (here is my speculation), since the inserted PATH element's namespace (`xhtml`) does not appear in the DOM, it would not be saved when saving the page. So, when opening the saved page, the PATH element's namespace would be correctly deduced (possibly inheriting from the SVG element), resulting in the SVG appearing as it should.

A duplicate of the bug report mentioned above is [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1080471) and is provided here for more insight.

I tried the approach suggested above in a commercial cross-browser testing platform using Vista and Firefox 35 (I too like to live dangerously) and the console log was `svg`/`svg`/`xhtml`. Using Firefox 36 the console log was `svg`/`svg`/`svg`.

What works in Firefox 35 for appending the PATH to the SVG is this:

```
var svgid = document.getElementById('svg_main');
var str_lne = 60;
var pathEl = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
pathEl.setAttribute('id', 'lineAB');
pathEl.setAttribute('d', 'M 50 ' + str_lne + ' L 1050 ' + str_lne);
pathEl.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0.5,0.5)');
pathEl.style.stroke = '#707073';
pathEl.style.strokeWidth = '1px';
svgid.appendChild(pathEl);
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x1j393u0/2/). That is, create your elements explicity and do not insert HTML directly.

The million dollar question now. Why do you care about Firefox 35 or below?

Comment: Now I'm working in science project. I'm developing the tool for biologist. I was seen most of the scientist have the old version of OS (windows xp, fedora 14 like as) and old version of the browser (but i'm not consider the IE).  I cann't tell "please update your system and please install the newest version of firefox" because they haven't time. They want only result. That the reason I'm care about the all browser.

Comment: @mkHun I understand that you are in a tough situation, probably because of dynamics. But you should handle it carefully. You may waste a lot of time trying to be compatible with old browsers that are lacking. It would make sense, possibly, if you were developing something commercial for the public. But for something so targeted, I believe it would be perfectly natural to require a minimum version of a browser (Firefox 36 in your case, if you want to code SVG freely). Or, better, to declare that this has been tested on Firefox ??. Major changes are not so frequent. Anyway, it is your call.

Comment: The `appendchild` is working on firefox 35 and below version. :)

Comment: @mkHun ;) I really hope you will not need to ask questions like this one in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code works just fine in Firefox.  Apart from the fact you have a typo (`storke-width`).

```js
var svgid = document.getElementById('svg_main');
var str_lne = 60;
var data = '<path id="lineAB" d="M 50 '+str_lne+' L 1050 '+(str_lne)+'" transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"  stroke="#707073" fill="none"  stroke-width="1px" opacity="1" ></path>';
svgid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',data);
```

```html
<div style="height:330px; width:1100px; background:#313131; margin:0 auto; ">
    <svg id='svg_main' height="330" width="1100"></svg>
</div>
```